# Oracle how to keep order in a hierarchical view when using 'in' condition clause

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, given a hierarchical view V powered by `connect by`, which may represent a hierarchical query already order siblings by some logic.

if do the query against V like this:

```
select * from V where key_column in (any subquery may return key_columns in a different order)
```

how can we keep the original order in view V?

I know I can add a rownum column to the view, then order by it, but I am looking a method in sql, I don't want to change view's structure.

the view:

```
CREATE or replace VIEW
    CWE_DICT_TREE_VIEW
    AS
SELECT
    SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (a.node_id, '.'), 2)   AS id_path,
    SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (a.entry_key, '.'), 2) AS key_path,
    getdictname(parent_node)                           AS parent_entry_value,
    LEVEL                                              AS node_level,
    CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF                                  AS node_is_leaf,
    a.*
FROM
    cwe_dict a START WITH a.parent_node IS NULL CONNECT BY PRIOR a.node_id = a.parent_node ORDER
    SIBLINGS BY a.inline_sort_no;
```

the query:

```
select NODE_ID , PARENT_NODE , ENTRY_VALUE , NODE_IS_LEAF , INLINE_SORT_NO , NODE_LEVEL , ENTRY_KEY
from CWE_DICT_TREE_VIEW where NODE_ID in ( 
    with link(NODE_ID,PARENT_NODE) AS ( 
        select NODE_ID,PARENT_NODE from CWE_DICT_TREE_VIEW WHERE ( ENTRY_VALUE like '%农%') or( ENTRY_KEY like '%农%' ) 
        union all 
        select P2.NODE_ID, P2.PARENT_NODE from LINK P1  inner join CWE_DICT_TREE_VIEW P2 on P2.NODE_ID = P1.PARENT_NODE
    ) 
    select distinct NODE_ID from LINK 
 )
```

Comment: Use the `order by` clause at the end. Please google it!

Comment: The ordering in the view is only so the view has sufficient definition to complete the specified functionality.  Once the data is selected from the view the data set retains a universal property of all data sets in SQL : they posses no inherent ordering whatsoever.  The only way for a data set to present with a particular order is for the Outer Most query to have an `ORDER BY` clause.  It doesn't matter what's in your views, sub queries, joins, or anything else; the ***only*** way to ***guarantee*** that a client receives data in a particular order is with an `ORDER BY` on the outermost query.

Comment: @MatBailie in my case, do you think adding a 'rownum' column to my view is the only option ?

Comment: Your `CWE_DICT_TREE_VIEW` certainly needs some fields for you to order by.  By be a `rownum`, maybe also a `depth` field, it just depends on what you know you're going to want to order this data by.

Answer (score 1):

> How can we keep the original order in view V?

You have a profound misunderstanding about tables and relational databases.  Tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "original order" in a table.  The only ordering is the ordering that you specify in a query.

Tables often have an "id" type of primary key that provides the "natural ordering".  Simply include this column in the `order by`.  Say it is `key_column`:

```
select *
from V
where key_column in (any subquery may return key_columns in a different order)
order by key_column;
```